# Header Names and Skip first row

Tags: powershell

Excel source: has 2 columns and 2 rows (and first row has header)

Below mentioned code imports blank row in database...

But if remove -Skip 1 - it imports both rows (one has header and other has value)

```
Import-CSV $DestinationFile -Header Col1, Col2 | Select-Object -Skip 1
ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.Col1)','$($_.Col2)')"}
```

Can someone advise whats wrong with above code, we want header to be skipped and giving custom name to headers (as header names in file are big)

Comment: Remove `-Header Col1, Col2`.

Comment: Also, you need to connect the 2 lines with a pipe, otherwise the second line won't receive the output of the first line as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import-CSV assumes that the first row of the given csv file is a header. So, if you use the -header switch and specify a header, Import-CSV uses the first row in the csv file as a data row as well.

Furthermore, you forgot to pipe the imported csv object into the foreach-object loop.

```
Import-CSV $DestinationFile | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.Col1)','$($_.Col2)')"}
```